# Calculate billing for per day based on difference between start and end date

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, datetime, amazon-redshift

I have data in table as below:

| Account Id | Amount | Start_date | End_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 10 | 2023-11-16 17:00:00 | 2023-11-16 18:00:00 |
| 123 | 10 | 2023-11-16 02:00:00 | 2023-11-17 02:00:00 |
| 123 | 20 | 2023-11-17 17:00:00 | 2023-11-17 18:00:00 |
| 123 | 30 | 2023-11-18 02:00:00 | 2023-11-20 02:00:00 |
| 123 | 10 | 2023-11-18 17:00:00 | 2023-11-18 18:00:00 |
| 123 | 20 | 2023-11-19 02:00:00 | 2023-11-20 02:00:00 |

I need to calculate the amount for per day for one Cloud Id.
For ex - For Cloud Id 123, in the first row, the start date and end date has interval of 1 so amount of 10 will be included for date of 2023-11-16. The second row, the difference between start date and second day is 2, so the amount of 10 will be calculated for date of 16 as 10/2(difference) i.e. 2 and for date of 17 as 10/2 = 5.

11-16    10+5 = 15
11-17    5+20 = 25
11-18    10+10= 20
11-19    10+10= 20

I need to write a query to get the results in above way.

so far I have tried the following query but I am getting syntax error -

```
select start_date, end_date, account_id, amount, datediff(day, start_date, end_date) as interval into #temp 
from billing where account_id = '123';

select * from #temp;
drop table if exists #result;
select account_id, start_date, end_date, interval, 
  CASE WHEN interval = 0 THEN amount ELSE amount/(interval + 1) END AS per_day_cost
INTO #result
UNION ALL
SELECT  account_id, start_date, end_date, interval, 
  CASE WHEN interval = 0 THEN amount ELSE amount/(interval + 1) END AS per_day_cost
FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3)) as v(n) CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT account_id, start_date, end_date, interval, amount FROM #temp) s
where v.n <= interval
order by account_id;

select * from #result;
```

Comment: Redshift and SQL Server are *entirely* different products. Please (re)tag the product you are really using.

Comment: I am using amazon redshift. I am getting error editing the tag. Can someone pls add the tag.

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing the following query for my question -

```
WITH toolsdatastats AS  --gets the min and max date among all records
    (
        SELECT trunc(min(start_date)) earliestdate,  trunc(max(end_date)) latestdate
        FROM billing
    ),
    dates AS  --gets the full date from system between the min and max dates found earlier
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM date_d
        WHERE fulldate >= (SELECT earliestdate FROM toolsdatastats)
            AND fulldate <= (SELECT latestdate FROM toolsdatastats)
    ),
    dailydata AS
    (
        SELECT fulldate full_date, account_id, amount, start_date, end_date,
            CASE
                WHEN td.start_date < dates.fulldate
                    THEN dates.fulldate
                ELSE td.start_date
            END AS usage_start_for_the_day,
            CASE
                WHEN td.end_date > DATEADD(day, 1, dates.fulldate)
                    THEN DATEADD(day, 1, dates.fulldate)
                ELSE td.end_date
            END AS usage_end_for_the_day
        FROM billing td
        JOIN dates on dates.fulldate>=trunc(td.start_date) and dates.fulldate<=trunc(td.end_date)
        ORDER BY account_id, fulldate
    ),
    dailycost as 
    (
      select full_date, account_id, usage_start_for_the_day, usage_end_for_the_day, start_date, end_date,
        CASE 
          WHEN (full_date = trunc(start_date) and trunc(usage_start_for_the_day) = trunc(usage_end_for_the_day))
          THEN amount
          ELSE amount/(datediff(day, start_date, end_date) + 1) 
        END AS amount
        from dailydata
    )
    select full_date, account_id, sum (amount) from dailycost group by full_date, account_id order by full_date;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change a little bit your query (without using temporary tables)

```
SELECT  account_id, start_date, end_date
   ,datediff(day, start_date, end_date) interval
   ,amount/(datediff(day, start_date, end_date) + 1)AS per_day_cost
   ,Id, amount as pAmount  -- only for debug
FROM (VALUES (0),(1), (2), (3)) as v(n) 
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT account_id, start_date, end_date
     ,datediff(day, start_date, end_date) interval
     ,amount ,Id
   FROM billing
  ) s
where v.n <= datediff(day, start_date, end_date)
order by account_id;
```

I'll add Id column to test table for clarity only.
For test data

```
create table billing (Id int,Account_Id int,Amount float,Start_date datetime,   End_date datetime);
insert into test values
 (1,123,    10,'2023-11-16 17:00:00','2023-11-16 18:00:00')
,(2,123,    10,'2023-11-16 02:00:00','2023-11-17 02:00:00')
,(3,123,    20,'2023-11-17 17:00:00','2023-11-17 18:00:00')
,(4,123,    30,'2023-11-18 02:00:00','2023-11-20 02:00:00')
,(5,123,    10,'2023-11-18 17:00:00','2023-11-18 18:00:00')
,(6,123,    20,'2023-11-19 02:00:00','2023-11-20 02:00:00')
;
```

result is

| account_id | start_date | end_date | interval | per_day_cost | Id | pAmount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2023-11-16 17:00:00.000 | 2023-11-16 18:00:00.000 | 0 | 10 | 1 | 10 |
| 123 | 2023-11-16 02:00:00.000 | 2023-11-17 02:00:00.000 | 1 | 5 | 2 | 10 |
| 123 | 2023-11-16 02:00:00.000 | 2023-11-17 02:00:00.000 | 1 | 5 | 2 | 10 |
| 123 | 2023-11-17 17:00:00.000 | 2023-11-17 18:00:00.000 | 0 | 20 | 3 | 20 |
| 123 | 2023-11-18 02:00:00.000 | 2023-11-20 02:00:00.000 | 2 | 10 | 4 | 30 |
| 123 | 2023-11-18 02:00:00.000 | 2023-11-20 02:00:00.000 | 2 | 10 | 4 | 30 |
| 123 | 2023-11-18 02:00:00.000 | 2023-11-20 02:00:00.000 | 2 | 10 | 4 | 30 |
| 123 | 2023-11-18 17:00:00.000 | 2023-11-18 18:00:00.000 | 0 | 10 | 5 | 10 |
| 123 | 2023-11-19 02:00:00.000 | 2023-11-20 02:00:00.000 | 1 | 10 | 6 | 20 |
| 123 | 2023-11-19 02:00:00.000 | 2023-11-20 02:00:00.000 | 1 | 10 | 6 | 20 |

You can join table and "series" query v(n) in direct order

```
SELECT  billing.* 
   ,datediff(day, start_date, end_date) interval
   ,amount/(datediff(day, start_date, end_date) + 1)AS per_day_cost
   ,amount as pAmount  -- only for debug
FROM billing
left join (select 0 n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3)v
   on v.n <= datediff(day, start_date, end_date)
order by account_id;
```

Comment: Have you tried the query in AWS Redshift.  I am running it and I get the error - ```Invalid operation: function values(integer, integer, integer, integer)  does not exist 
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.;```

Comment: Use ``(select 0 n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3)v`` instead ``values(...)`` - as shown in last example.

Comment: Thanks! That worked! But how do I calculate cost for a day ?

Comment: For cost for a day Group by account_id,start_date and sum(per_day_cost)

Comment: I want something like this - 16-11     10+5 = 15 
17-11    5+20  = 25
18-11   10+10  =20
19-11   10+10  =20
20-11   10+10  =20